# Prove that if $p$ and $p^2+2$ are prime then $p^3+2$ is prime too

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, prime-factorization

I'm trying to figure out how to prove that if $p$ and $p^2+2$ are prime numbers then $p^3+2$ is a prime number too.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: The trick is that $p$ and $p^2 + 2$ are almost never both prime. Have you tried some examples?

Comment: Hint: Find what is $p\mod3.$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what about 3, 3 is prime and 11 is prime and 29 is prime !

Comment: Prime numbers greater than $3$ are always $\pm1\bmod 6$. So $p^2+2\equiv 3\bmod 6$, and hence a multiple of $3$ (meaning not prime).

Comment: @Nizar: I said "almost never," not "never."

Comment: The two statements "almost never" and "never" are equivalent mod 3

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269790/why-does-p28-prime-imply-p34-prime

Answer (score 9):

If $p=2$, then $p^2+2$ is not prime.

If $p=3$, then $p^2+2 = 11$, then $p^3+2=29$ is prime.

If $p>3$, then $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3$, then $p^2+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. So, $p^2+2$ is not prime.

Comment: For clarity you might want to add that the statement given by the OP is thus true...

Comment: So it works only for 3?

Comment: Why do you bother to isolate the case $p = 2$ -- the logic holds for the same reason in the $p > 3$ case.

Comment: Sure, you're right. Thank you very much guys, I understood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the difference of squares formula to get that $p^2 + 2 = (p+1)(p-1) + 3$. Since $p^2$ is prime, $(p+1)(p-1)$ cannot have a factor $3$ as it would imply that $p^2 + 2$ is divisible by $3$ hence not a square. Among three consecutive integers one has to be divisible by $3$. Since neither $p+1$ or $p-1$ is divisible by $3$, $p$ must be. $p$ is a prime number and the only prime divisble by $3$ is $3$ itself, hence $p =3$ and $p^3 + 2 = 29$, a prime.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Your answer may be easier to read and more likely to be voted on if you edit your post using [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make it easier to read.