# Squares, Cubes and Prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $p$  and $p^2+2$ are prime numbers, prove that $p^3+2$ is also a prime number. Actually I do not know what is the relationship among square numbers, cube numbers and prime numbers

Comment: This is a trick problem. There's only one such possible prime $p$ so that $p^2+2$ is prime...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what do you mean ? $3$ and $7$ seem to be such primes

Comment: Is $7^2+2$ prime? @G.T.R

Comment: Oops, my bad @ThomasAndrews

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269790/why-does-p28-prime-imply-p34-prime  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234077/prime-p-with-p28-prime

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $p \equiv \pm 1 \mod 3$, then what is $p^2 + 2 \mod 3$? How many primes $p$ are there such that $p^2 + 2$ is also prime?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different take on Matthew's approach.  Multiply $p$ by $p^2+2$.  You get $p^3+2p$.  You know that $p^3\equiv p\bmod 3$ from Fermat's Little Theorem, therefore $p^3+2p\equiv 3p$ is a multiple of $3$.  If both of your factors $p$ and $p^2+2$ are *prime* factors of this multiple of $3$, then one factor must be exactly $3$.  Alas, $p^2+2=3$ implies $p=1$ which does not qualify as a prime, so there is only one more possibility to check.