# Show that $p^3+4$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ and $p^2 +8$ are both prime number, prove that $p^3 +4$ is also prime.

I was thinking using two cases for even and odd. So $p$ is even thus there is no prime, the statement does not hold. So, $p$ is odd, $p$ has to be of the form of $2k+1$.

let $p=2k+1$ which is prime

$(2k+1)^2 + 8 = 4k^2+4k+1+8 = 2(2k^2+2k+4)+1$ which is prime

so $(2k+1)^3 +4 = 8k^3+12k^2+6k+1 +4= 2(4k^3+6k^2+3k+2)+1$ which is also prime.

is that all that i need to show

Comment: Note: 2 is even but also prime.  However, for p=2, note that p^2+8=12, which isn't prime.  Thus, p=2 isn't even a candidate meeting the hypotheses.  You can make an observation of this in your proof, and then just deal with the case of p odd.

Comment: Note that you have proved that $p^3+4$ is odd, not prime.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass In reality, you don't need to take $2$ as a special case at all.

Comment: Yeah i see that, that is one of the reason why i post it. I did feel like the proof did not complete

Comment: That's what I said, Thomas Andrews.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Why does $p^2+8$ prime imply $p^3+4$ prime](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269790/why-does-p28-prime-imply-p34-prime). See also: [Prime $p$ with $p^2+8$ prime](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234077/prime-p-with-p28-prime)

Answer (score 8):

No, as commenters have points out, all you've shown is that $p^3+4$ is odd.

Hint: What must $p$ be, modulo $3$?

Comment: what do you mean by what must p be modulo 3, and why modulo

Comment: Every natural number is of the form $3k,$, $3k+1$, or $3k+2$, which are called in number theory 0, 1 and 2, modulo $3$, respectively.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you don't know the theory of quadratic residue, you can note that every prime $p>3$ can be written in the form $6n\pm1$. It has remainder $\pm1$ when divided by $3$. Note therefore that for $p>3$, $p^2+8$ is divisible by $3$.
Indeed $$p^2+8=(6n\pm1)^2+8\equiv (\pm1)^2\!+8\equiv 0\pmod{\!3}$$

Comment: $5$ and $11$ are not of the form $6n+1$ :-)

Comment: But 6n\pm 1 yes

Comment: But why $6n\pm1$ when you can do $3n\pm1$?

Comment: $3n\pm 1 $ is even, it doesn't rappresent a prime number

Comment: But does one *need* that? Did you read Thomas' answer?