# If $p$ and $p^2+2$ prime, then $p^3+2$ prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

first time doing such a proof. I somehow can't make it work, where's the problem?

Claim: If $p$ and $p^2 + 2$ is prime, then $p^3+2$ is prime.
Proof:

Basic idea: Since we are always adding $2$, we are cheking the remainder of modulo $3$.

Case: $p=2$

this doesn't hold the claim, omit.

Case: $p=3$

since 3 is prim and $p^2+2=11$ is prime, we calculate $p^3+2=29$ which is also prime.

We now check for the remainder of mod $3$. The idea is, that if $p$ is a prime and we take it mod $3$, we get $R_3(p)\in\{1,2\}$.

We can now make a case distinction.

Case 1: $R_3(p) = 1$

If that is the case, $p$ is prime. We check, if $p^2+2$ is prime:

$R_3(p^2+2)=R_3(R_3(p^2)+R_3(2))=R_3(R_3(R_3(p)\cdot R_3(p))+2)=R_3(R_3(1+2))=R_3(0)=0$. So $p^2+2$ isn't a prime. Thus, we can omit this case.

Case 2: $R_3(p) = 2$

$R_3(p^2+2)=R_3(R_3(p^2)+2)=R_3(R_3(R_3(p)R_3(p))+2)=R_3(R_3(6))=0$

This case doesn't hold either.

So somewhere in my though process I made a terrible mistake but I can't see where. :/

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234077/prime-p-with-p28-prime

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269790/why-does-p28-prime-imply-p34-prime).

Comment: Thanks - kind of buffled.

Comment: Baffled, you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a perfectly good solution to me. You have correctly proved that the only prime $p$ for which $p^2+2$ is also prime is $p=3$. And for $p=3$ you've checked that $p^3+2$ is also prime. So the result is true.

Comment: They wrote it as if it is a true statement, so I'm expecting it to be true for such primes. So are you sure?

Comment: "Such primes" is only the prime 3, and the statement is true for p=3. The 'if' clause does not apply to other primes, so those primes cannot falsify the statement. The statement is therefore true.